# How to convert string of integers to int array?

Tags: arrays, swift

How can the following string be converted into an integer array?

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Generic Algorithm: split the string on commas - this will result in an array of strings. Convert the array of strings into an array of ints. Implementation: Just Do It; might have a useful answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

You can use componentsSeparatedByString method to convert your string to an array and use flatMap to convert it to Int:

```
let str = "1,2,3,4,5"
let arr = str.components(separatedBy: ",").flatMap{Int($0)}

print(arr)  // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\n"
```

If your string contains spaces also you can trim it using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet  before converting to Int:

```
let str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5 "
let numbers = str.components(separatedBy: ",")
    .flatMap{ Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }

print(numbers)  // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\n"
```

Comment: Right on!  Thanks.

Comment: flatMap is deprecated. compactMap can be used instead